# Python library for calculating next and previous time of the cron-like scheduled task

Tags: python, datetime, scheduled-tasks

I needed a task system that would let me define a cron-like rule in the database, and be able to find the next and the previous time when the task was and is supposed to happen.

I am running a web application, so ways like run a scheduled and check for every minute, or other ways around does not work for me, so I had to come up with an algorithm. It also should support more complicated jobs, like:

**Example 1**: Task runs every Tuesday at 3:00pm, find the previous execution time

**Example 2**: next presidential election day in the USA (which is, "the Tuesday next after the first Monday in the month of November"), find the next execution time (November, 3, 2020).

This was not trivial. Here is the result:

[Github page with tests, documentation and more examples](https://github.com/leonidumanskiy/scheduledtask/tree/c98c403dad95146ea6aac8fee71a7659b3c7209c)

Here is the example of how to find the next presidential election day (with a bit of cheating, because we find the first Monday of November and take the next day after it).

```
from scheduledtask import ScheduledTask

# Finding the next presidential election day in the USA
task = ScheduledTask(minutes=[0], hours=[0], days_of_week=[0], days_of_week_num=[0], months=[11], 
                     years=range(1848, 9999, 4))
print(task.get_next_time() + timedelta(days=1))
print(task.get_previous_time() + timedelta(days=1))
```

The algorithm supports multiple strategies (using days_of_month and days_of_week together is not supported). You can define every term (minutes, hours, days, days_of_week, days_of_week_num, weeks, months, years) as a list of values, range (supports step), or None (which is like a star * in cron).

**So, here is how the algorithm works in a nutshell:**

1. Takes the highest term (years)
2. Figures the next year that matches the rule
3. If it does, it switches to the next term (month), tries to find the next matching value. If the value is found, it switches to the next term (days), if there is no possible values, it switches back to the year, finds the next possible year that matches the rule, and starts all over again.
4. And so on, until we reach the smallest term that matches the rule, or the biggest term is out of options (that means there is no next/previous datetime found).

This is pretty simple, but there are also many edge cases and conditions that we have to check (leap years, number of weeks in a month and so on).

Here is the library:

```
from datetime import datetime
from enum import Enum
from copy import copy
from .utils import get_biggest_value_less_or_equal_to, get_smallest_value_greater_or_equal_to, last, first, \
    weekday_num, weekday_and_num_to_day, num_days_in_month, weekday_and_week_to_day, week_num, max_week_num


class DateTimeHolder:
    __slots__ = ['minute', 'hour', 'day', 'day_of_week', 'day_of_week_num', 'month', 'week', 'year']

    def __init__(self, minute=None, hour=None, day=None, day_of_week=None, day_of_week_num=None, week=None,
                 month=None, year=None):
        self.minute = minute
        self.hour = hour
        self.day = day
        self.day_of_week = day_of_week
        self.day_of_week_num = day_of_week_num
        self.week = week
        self.month = month
        self.year = year

    @property
    def datetime(self):
        if self.day_of_week is not None and self.day_of_week_num is not None:
            day = weekday_and_num_to_day(self.year, self.month, self.day_of_week_num, self.day_of_week)
            return datetime(self.year, self.month, day, self.hour or 0, self.minute or 0)
        elif self.day_of_week is not None and self.week is not None:
            day = weekday_and_week_to_day(self.year, self.month, self.week, self.day_of_week)
            return datetime(self.year, self.month, day, self.hour or 0, self.minute or 0)
        else:
            return datetime(self.year, self.month or 1, self.day or 1, self.hour or 0, self.minute or 0)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
            return getattr(self, key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
            return setattr(self, key, value)

    def __copy__(self):
        return DateTimeHolder(minute=self.minute, hour=self.hour, day=self.day, day_of_week=self.day_of_week,
                              day_of_week_num=self.day_of_week_num, week=self.week, month=self.month, year=self.year)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.datetime < other.datetime

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.datetime > other.datetime

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.datetime == other.datetime

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self.datetime <= other.datetime

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self.datetime >= other.datetime


class TaskStrategy(Enum):
    days_of_month = 0  # 1-31
    days_of_week = 1  # Sun-Sat + week number
    days_of_week_num = 2  # Sun-Sat + weekday number


class DayStrategyFraction(Enum):
    minute = 0
    hour = 1
    day = 2
    month = 3
    year = 4


class DayOfWeekStrategyFraction(Enum):
    minute = 0
    hour = 1
    day_of_week = 2
    week = 3
    month = 4
    year = 5


class DayOfWeekNumStrategyFraction(Enum):
    minute = 0
    hour = 1
    day_of_week = 2
    day_of_week_num = 3
    month = 4
    year = 5


class ScheduledTask:
    def __init__(self, minutes=None, hours=None, days=None, days_of_week=None, days_of_week_num=None, weeks=None,
                 months=None, years=None, max_iterations=100):
        if days_of_week is not None and days_of_week_num is not None:
            self.strategy = TaskStrategy.days_of_week_num
            self.fractions = DayOfWeekNumStrategyFraction
            self.candidates = [minutes or range(0, 60), hours or range(0, 24), days_of_week or range(0, 7),
                               days_of_week_num or range(0, 5), months or range(1, 13), years or range(0, 9999)]

        elif days_of_week is not None or weeks is not None:
            self.strategy = TaskStrategy.days_of_week
            self.fractions = DayOfWeekStrategyFraction
            self.candidates = [minutes or range(0, 60), hours or range(0, 24), days_of_week or range(0, 7),
                               weeks or range(0, 6), months or range(1, 13), years or range(0, 9999)]

        else:
            self.strategy = TaskStrategy.days_of_month
            self.fractions = DayStrategyFraction
            self.candidates = [minutes or range(0, 60), hours or range(0, 24), days or range(1, 32),
                               months or range(1, 13), years or range(0, 9999)]

        self.highest_fraction = last([f for f in self.fractions])

        # Settings
        self.max_iterations = max_iterations

    def _datetimeholder_valid(self, datetimeholder: DateTimeHolder, fraction: Enum):
        """Check if date time holder is valid for current fraction
           i.e. if fraction is days, check if current day exists in the month
        """
        # Check min value
        if self.strategy == TaskStrategy.days_of_month:
            min_value = 1 if fraction in [self.fractions.day, self.fractions.month, self.fractions.year] else 0
        else:
            min_value = 1 if fraction in [self.fractions.month, self.fractions.year] else 0

        if datetimeholder[fraction.name] < min_value:
            return False

        # Check if day exceeds number of days in that month
        if self.strategy == TaskStrategy.days_of_month and fraction == self.fractions.day:
            n_days_in_month = num_days_in_month(datetimeholder.year, datetimeholder.month)
            if datetimeholder.day > n_days_in_month:
                return False

        # Check if day of week number exceeds number of day of weeks for this month
        if self.strategy == TaskStrategy.days_of_week_num and fraction == self.fractions.day_of_week_num:
            # Since we don't know what day of week we are validating,
            # assume that this number can't be more than max week number
            if datetimeholder.day_of_week_num > max_week_num(datetimeholder.year, datetimeholder.month):
                return False

        # Check if day of week and day of week number exceeds maximum day of week number for this month
        if self.strategy == TaskStrategy.days_of_week_num and fraction == self.fractions.day_of_week:
            day = weekday_and_num_to_day(datetimeholder.year, datetimeholder.month, datetimeholder.day_of_week_num,
                                         datetimeholder.day_of_week)
            n_days_in_month = num_days_in_month(datetimeholder.year, datetimeholder.month)
            if day > n_days_in_month:
                return False

        # Check if month has n weeks
        if self.strategy == TaskStrategy.days_of_week and fraction == self.fractions.week:
            if datetimeholder.week > max_week_num(datetimeholder.year, datetimeholder.month):
                return False

        # Check if weekday and week number combination
        if self.strategy == TaskStrategy.days_of_week and fraction == self.fractions.day_of_week:
            day = weekday_and_week_to_day(datetimeholder.year, datetimeholder.month, datetimeholder.week,
                                          datetimeholder.day_of_week)
            n_days_in_month = num_days_in_month(datetimeholder.year, datetimeholder.month)
            if day > n_days_in_month:
                return False

        # All checks are passed
        return True

    def _datetimeholders_equal(self, a: DateTimeHolder, b: DateTimeHolder, from_fraction: Enum):
        """Partially check a and b date time holders for equality, starting with fraction.
           For example, if the fraction is DAY, compare only DAY, MONTH and YEAR
        """
        return all([a[self.fractions(fv).name] == b[self.fractions(fv).name] for fv
                    in range(from_fraction.value, self.highest_fraction.value+1)])

    def _datetimeholders_compare(self, a: DateTimeHolder, b: DateTimeHolder, from_fraction: Enum):
        """Partially compare a and b date time holders, starting with fraction.
           For example, if the fraction is DAY, compare only DAY, MONTH and YEAR
        """
        _a = DateTimeHolder()
        _b = DateTimeHolder()
        for fraction_value in range(from_fraction.value, self.highest_fraction.value+1):
            fraction = self.fractions(fraction_value)
            _a[fraction.name] = a[fraction.name]
            _b[fraction.name] = b[fraction.name]
        if _a > _b:
            return 1
        elif _a == _b:
            return 0
        else:
            return -1

    def _increase_fraction(self, result: DateTimeHolder, fraction: Enum, increment: int, current: DateTimeHolder):
        """Increase fraction on the datetimeholder
        :param result:Value to increase
        :param fraction:Fraction to increase
        :param current:Original value - used to reset if we can't increase
        :return:Number of fractions increased (to know from which to recalculate)
        """
        # If candidates are range, perform step-aware increment
        if type(self.candidates[fraction.value]) == list:
            new_value = result[fraction.name] + increment
        elif type(self.candidates[fraction.value]) == range:
            new_value = result[fraction.name] + increment * self.candidates[fraction.value].step
        else:
            raise ValueError("candidate must be of type list or range")

        datetimeholder_increased = copy(result)
        datetimeholder_increased[fraction.name] = new_value
        if increment > 0:  # 1
            in_range = get_smallest_value_greater_or_equal_to(self.candidates[fraction.value],
                                                          datetimeholder_increased[fraction.name]) is not None
        else:  # -1
            in_range = get_biggest_value_less_or_equal_to(self.candidates[fraction.value],
                                                          datetimeholder_increased[fraction.name]) is not None

        if self._datetimeholder_valid(datetimeholder_increased, fraction) and in_range:
            result[fraction.name] = new_value
            return 1
        else:
            if fraction == self.highest_fraction:
                raise ValueError("Can't increase fraction - current " + self.highest_fraction +
                                 " is " + result[fraction.value])
            result[fraction.name] = current[fraction.name]
            return 1 + self._increase_fraction(result, self.fractions(fraction.value + 1), increment, current)

    def get_next_time(self, current_datetime: datetime = None):
        """Returns next task execution time nearest to the given datetime
        """
        if current_datetime is None:
            current_datetime = datetime.utcnow()

        if self.strategy == TaskStrategy.days_of_month:
            current = DateTimeHolder(minute=current_datetime.minute, hour=current_datetime.hour,
                                     day=current_datetime.day, month=current_datetime.month, year=current_datetime.year)

        elif self.strategy == TaskStrategy.days_of_week:
            current = DateTimeHolder(minute=current_datetime.minute, hour=current_datetime.hour,
                                     day_of_week=current_datetime.weekday(),
                                     week=week_num(current_datetime),
                                     month=current_datetime.month, year=current_datetime.year)

        else:
            current = DateTimeHolder(minute=current_datetime.minute, hour=current_datetime.hour,
                                     day_of_week=current_datetime.weekday(),
                                     day_of_week_num=weekday_num(current_datetime),
                                     month=current_datetime.month, year=current_datetime.year)

        result = self._get_next_time(current)
        return result.datetime

    def get_previous_time(self, current_datetime: datetime = None):
        """Returns previous task execution time nearest to the given datetime
        """
        if current_datetime is None:
            current_datetime = datetime.utcnow()

        if self.strategy == TaskStrategy.days_of_month:
            current = DateTimeHolder(minute=current_datetime.minute, hour=current_datetime.hour,
                                     day=current_datetime.day, month=current_datetime.month, year=current_datetime.year)

        elif self.strategy == TaskStrategy.days_of_week:
            current = DateTimeHolder(minute=current_datetime.minute, hour=current_datetime.hour,
                                     day_of_week=current_datetime.weekday(),
                                     week=week_num(current_datetime),
                                     month=current_datetime.month, year=current_datetime.year)

        else:
            current = DateTimeHolder(minute=current_datetime.minute, hour=current_datetime.hour,
                                     day_of_week=current_datetime.weekday(),
                                     day_of_week_num=weekday_num(current_datetime),
                                     month=current_datetime.month, year=current_datetime.year)

        result = self._get_previous_time(current)
        return result.datetime

    def _get_next_time(self, current: DateTimeHolder):
        """Calculates next task time using current
        """
        result = DateTimeHolder()
        fraction_value = self.highest_fraction.value
        i = 0
        while fraction_value != -1:  # From year to minute
            i += 1
            if i > self.max_iterations:  # Max iteration check
                raise ValueError("maximum number of iterations exceeded. You found a bug with scheduledtask. Dump: " +
                                 "candidates: {}, ".format(self.candidates) +
                                 "current: {}, max_iterations: {}".format(current, self.max_iterations))

            fraction = self.fractions(fraction_value)
            if fraction is self.highest_fraction \
                    or self._datetimeholders_equal(result, current, self.fractions(fraction_value+1)):
                result[fraction.name] = get_smallest_value_greater_or_equal_to(self.candidates[fraction_value],
                                                                               current[fraction.name])
            else:
                result[fraction.name] = first(self.candidates[fraction_value])

            if result[fraction.name] is None \
                    or not self._datetimeholder_valid(result, fraction) \
                    or not self._datetimeholders_compare(result, current, fraction) > -1:  # In case with day_of_week_num
                if fraction == self.highest_fraction:
                    return None  # Can't find highest fraction match, event never happened in the past

                # Decrease higher fractions on result datetime, recalculate starting from that fraction-1
                fraction_value += self._increase_fraction(result, self.fractions(fraction_value + 1), +1, current) - 1
                continue

            fraction_value -= 1
        return result

    def _get_previous_time(self, current: DateTimeHolder):
        """Calculates previous task time using current
        """
        result = DateTimeHolder()
        fraction_value = self.highest_fraction.value
        i = 0
        while fraction_value != -1:  # From year to minute
            i += 1
            if i > self.max_iterations:  # Max iteration check
                raise ValueError("maximum number of iterations exceeded. You found a bug with scheduledtask. Dump: " +
                                 "candidates: {}, ".format(self.candidates) +
                                 "current: {}, max_iterations: {}".format(current, self.max_iterations))

            fraction = self.fractions(fraction_value)
            if fraction is self.highest_fraction \
                    or self._datetimeholders_equal(result, current, self.fractions(fraction_value + 1)):
                result[fraction.name] = get_biggest_value_less_or_equal_to(self.candidates[fraction_value],
                                                                           current[fraction.name])
            else:
                result[fraction.name] = last(self.candidates[fraction_value])

            if result[fraction.name] is None \
                    or not self._datetimeholder_valid(result, fraction) \
                    or not self._datetimeholders_compare(result, current, fraction) < 1:  # In case with day_of_week_num
                if fraction == self.highest_fraction:
                    return None  # Can't find highest fraction match, event never happened in the past

                # Decrease higher fractions on result datetime, recalculate starting from that fraction-1
                fraction_value += self._increase_fraction(result, self.fractions(fraction_value + 1), -1, current) - 1
                continue

            fraction_value -= 1
        return result
```

utils.py:

```
from datetime import datetime
from calendar import monthrange

def get_biggest_value_less_or_equal_to(iter: list or range, value):
    """Returns the biggest element from the list that is less or equal to the value. Return None if not found
    """
    if type(iter) == list:
        i = [x for x in iter if x <= value]
        return max(i) if i else None

    elif type(iter) == range:
        if value in range(iter.start, iter.stop):  # Value lies within this range, return step-aware value
            return value - ((value - iter.start) % iter.step)
        elif value > iter.stop-1:  # value is greater than range, return last element of range
            return iter.stop-1
        else:  # value is less than range, return None
            return None

    else:
        raise ValueError("iter must be of type list or range")


def get_smallest_value_greater_or_equal_to(iter: list or range, value):
    """Returns the smallest element from the list that is greater or equal to the value. Return None if not found
    """
    if type(iter) == list:
        i = [x for x in iter if x >= value]
        return min(i) if i else None

    elif type(iter) == range:
        if value in range(iter.start, iter.stop):  # Value lies within this range, return step-aware value
            return value + (iter.step - ((value - iter.start) % iter.step)) % iter.step
        elif value < iter.start:  # Value is less than range start, return start
            return iter.start
        else:  # Value is greater than range, return None
            return None

    else:
        raise ValueError("iter must be of type list or range")


def last(iter: list or range):
    """Returns the last element from the list or range
    """
    if type(iter) == list:
        return iter[len(iter)-1]
    elif type(iter) == range:
        return iter.stop - (iter.stop - 1 - iter.start) % iter.step - 1  # Step-aware last element
    else:
        raise ValueError("iter must be of type list or range")


def first(iter: list or range):
    """Returns first element from the list or range
    """
    if type(iter) == list:
        return iter[0]
    elif type(iter) == range:
        return iter.start
    else:
        raise ValueError("iter must be of type list or range")


def num_days_in_month(year: int, month: int):
    return monthrange(year, month)[1]


def weekday_num(dt: datetime):
    """Returns number of weekday in the current month. I.e. if Tuesday is first in this month, returns 0
    """
    return int((dt.day - 1)/7)


def weekday_and_num_to_day(year: int, month: int, weekday_number: int, weekday: int):
    """Converts current year, month, weekday and weekday number into the day of month
    """
    dt_first = datetime(year, month, 1)
    dt_first_weekday = dt_first.weekday()
    return 1 - dt_first_weekday + weekday + ((0 if weekday >= dt_first_weekday else 1) + weekday_number) * 7


def weekday_and_week_to_day(year: int, month: int, week: int, weekday: int):
    """Converts current year, month, weekday and week number into the day of month
    """
    dt_first = datetime(year, month, 1)
    dt_first_weekday = dt_first.weekday()
    result = week * 7 + weekday - dt_first_weekday + 1
    if result < 1 or result > num_days_in_month(year, month):
        return None
    else:
        return result


def week_num(dt: datetime):
    """Returns week number of the given day
    """
    dt_first = dt.replace(day=1)
    dt_first_weekday = dt_first.weekday()
    return int((dt.day + dt_first_weekday - 1) / 7)


def max_week_num(year: int, month: int):
    """Returns number of weeks (Monday to Friday) that month contains
    """
    # The same thing as week number for the last day of month
    return week_num(datetime(year, month, num_days_in_month(year, month)))
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, you want to avoid using `type(x) == SomeType`. This is because Python relies quite often on duck-typing (If it looks like a duck, quacks like a duck...it's a duck).

So, for example your function `get_biggest_value_less_or_equal_to`. Theoretically, this function could take any iterable, but because of your type hints and usage of `type`, it can only take a list or range. Normally, you would want to use at least `isinstance(iter, list)`, which would also allow sub-classes of lists.

But here, I would let the function accept any `Iterable` and use it in the normal `max` call. Also, it is easier to ask for forgiveness than permission, so I would just call `max` in a generator expression and handle the exception that no value is below the threshold with a `try..except` block:

```
from typing import Iterable

def get_biggest_value_less_or_equal_to(iter: Iterable, value):
    """
    Returns the biggest element from the list that is less or equal to the value.
    Return None if not found.
    """
    # Special case for  range
    if isinstance(iter, range):
        if iter.start <= value < iter.stop:  # Value lies within this range, return step-aware value
            return value - ((value - iter.start) % iter.step)
        elif value >= iter.stop:  # value is greater than range, return last element of range
            return iter.stop-1
        else:  # value is less than range, return None
            return None

    try:
        return max(x for x in iter if x <= value)
    except ValueError:
        # iterator empty, no element <= value
        return None
```

You can do similar things with the other functions. Note that I made your docstring into a more common format. It is multi-line now and since it only starts in the second line of the string, the common indentation will be removed automatically.

```
def last(iter):
    """
    Returns the last element from the list or range
    """
    try:
        return iter[-1]
    except TypeError:
        raise ValueError("iter must be iterable")
```

Here you can use negative indexing, `l[len(l) - 1]` is the same as `l[-1]`. At first I had the special case in here as well, but `range` is subscriptable. If you *really* want the last bit of performance, you can use `iter.stop - iter.step`. This is slightly faster:

```
In [2]: r = range(100000000000)
In [3]: %timeit r[-1]
10000000 loops, best of 3: 155 ns per loop
In [4]: %timeit r.stop - r.step
10000000 loops, best of 3: 94 ns per loop
```

---

That being said, I have to say that I am not a big fan of type hinting. In this case it does not add anything. (It should be obvious that `iter` needs to be iterable. If you still pass something that is not iterable it will raise a helpful exception like `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` for example. If you want to, you can except that as well and display an even more helpful error message instead.)